# docker-compose, new container version and logs persistence

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Quite common use-case with docker-compose:

- A application's code pulled from a repository using git.
- A docker-compose.yml looking like this:

`version: '2'
    services:
        web:
          build: ./myapp`

When I want to deploy a new version I just pull the latest version of my code then make a `docker-compose up --build -d`.

Works almost perfectly except each time I make an update it erases my past logs accessible using `docker-compose logs`. I understand why docker behaves that way (even if docker-compose recreates a container with the same name it's still a brand new container, so it's quite logical logs get flushed). Still, it's really not practical.

Any one has a solution for that ? Preferably one that *does not* involve modifying images or using volumes to store logs. (Because that should be the whole point of docker logs, not having to worry about that).

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use one of the Logging Driver options described on the Docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

If this isn't a workable solution, can you give me a little more context for your goals and obstacles?

Answer (score -1):

You could redirect the output to a log file when starting the containers, something like:

```
docker-compose up --build --no-color --force-recreate &> logs &
```

Instead of `docker-compose logs` you could `tail logs` anytime you want.